# Make Azure Authentication Run Silently without Password Prompt

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I have a PowerShell script that connects to Azure, then downloads data.  The script runs great with human interaction, but I'm trying to run it silently as a scheduled task.  Currently, every time the script runs, it prompts for user credentials.  I change 'Always' to 'Never' and it doesn't seem to store the credentials for any length of time.

```
$clientId = "<CLIENTIDHERE>" # PowerShell clientId
$redirectUri = "<REDIRECTURIHERE>"
$MSGraphURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId"
$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
$authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($MSGraphURI, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Always")
$token = $authResult.AccessToken
```

Ideally the credentials would be passed through based on the credentials running in the scheduled task.  If that isn't an option, at least I'm hoping to put the username and password in the script and have the script send those credentials to authenticate.  How does one authenticate silently to Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  The initial authentication code I presented used an Azure-specific pop-up window to grab your credentials.  Using the following link [1] I converted the code to the PowerShell Get-Credential method instead.  From there, I used the information in this link [2] (Example 7) to configure the Get-Credential method to pull from plain text instead of a pop-up Window.

Now plain text passwords isn't ideal, but for our needs, it was good enough.

```
$clientId = "<CLIENTIDHERE>" # PowerShell clientId
$redirectUri = "REDIRECTURIHERE"
$MSGraphURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId"
$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority

$User = "<USERNAMEHERE>"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<PASSWORDHERE>" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

$AADCredential = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList $credential.UserName,$credential.Password

$authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($MSGraphURI, $clientId, $AADCredential)
$token = $authResult.AccessToken
```

[1] https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudlojik/2017/09/05/using-powershell-to-connect-to-microsoft-graph-api/

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

You could check the script shared by Bogdan Gavril from [this thread](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1130) .

```
#Require -Version 5.0
using namespace Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

$adalDll = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("<path_to>\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll")

$ADAuthorityURL = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/"
$resourceURL = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
$AADuserName = "foo"
$AADpassword = "bar"

Write-Host "Retrieving the AAD Credentials...";

$credential = New-Object UserPasswordCredential($AADuserName, $AADpassword);
$authenticationContext = New-Object AuthenticationContext($ADAuthorityURL);
$authenticationResult = [AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($authenticationContext, $resourceURL, $AADClientID, $credential).Result;

$ResultAAD = $authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```